# Multilevel Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, controls, logistic-regression, hierarchical

For a trainee-ship, I'm evaluating a pro-environmental initiative where members can advertise the initiative to their neighbors to convince them to join as well.

I want to predict group membership (binary) from a set of predictors:

1. Demographics (4 categorical, 2 continuous variables)
2. Psychological Variables (9 continuous variables)
3. Impressions of Neighborhood (8 continuous variables)
4. Impressions of the initiative (2 categorical, 2 continuous)

The data were collected in **30 different neighborhoods** so my supervisor suggested I control for neighborhood in my analysis.

***What I want to do now is:***

Add the four sets of predictors one after another to see if the model fit goes up--and, if so, due to which variables in the set--**while** controlling for neighborhood.

Is there any R package with documentation that will allow building such a model? Any literature tips on this kind of modeling, assumptions, interpretation of results, etc. are also more than welcome!

I have only worked with very basic multilevel models before, so I am kind of lost in this situation. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you have the right idea to use logistic regression.  I would just google 'logistic regression in R', and I'm sure you'll find plenty of videos, articles, examples on Stack Overflow, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any code in your question so may consider moving it to Cross Validated. As for learning how to model in R, Google will give [many suggestions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=glm+logistic+regression+in+R). But to give you a basic starting place

```
glm_out <- glm(group ~ D1 + ... + Neighborhood, family = binomial(), data = D)
```

where 'group' is your response, your predictors go where I've put `D1 + ...` and you include Neighborhood in the model as well. Nothing that you've described is nested so this should work to control for Neighborhood effects. Then you can use [stepAIC](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/stepAIC.html) from the MASS package to perform model selection.

```
glm_aic <- MASS::stepAIC(glm_out)
summary(glm_aic)
```

There are certainly other more complex procedures you could use.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!

I thought just including dummies for the Neighbourhood might not be sufficient because the ratio of partakers and non-partakers in the initiative differs quite a bit.

I now used the lme4 package to do a logistic regression model with a random intercept for each neighbourhood, would you say that is an equally viable method?

Also, is there a way to include whole sets of predictors stepwise, not just single predictors one after the other?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track -- if you're using lme you're already past my basic example, and yes definitely on the right track. It's hard to provide more help without example data and a specific question. I'm not sure what you mean by "include whole sets of predictors stepwise". Do you mean in the model formula? If so, you just need to do it...this it the human part of the analysis.